# Why can't ggplot separate plots from this example from the r4ds book?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am Learning R with the book R for Data Science 2017 - H.Wickham G.Grolemund I have a problem in the page 16 42/520. This is the code:

```
ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))

ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = drv))

ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_smooth(
mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv),
show.legend = FALSE
)
```

with this plot:

[image]

This is the text reference:

> Many geoms, like geom_smooth(), use a single geometric object to
> display multiple rows of data. For these geoms, you can set the group
> aesthetic to a categorical variable to draw multiple objects. ggplot2
> will draw a separate object for each unique value of the grouping
> variable. In practice, ggplot2 will automatically group the data for
> these geoms whenever you map an aesthetic to a discrete variable (as
> in the linetype example). It is convenient to rely on this feature
> because the group aesthetic by itself does not add a legend or
> distinguishing features to the geoms:

I try to reproduce but my plot is this:

[image]

I don't know if this is an version error or this way of plotting was deprecated.

Comment: It looks as though they are displaying the first plot on the left, the second in the middle, and the third on the right.  It's just typesetting.

Comment: Look at the code again more closely. The code is for 3 different plots. When you run it all at once, you are seeing just the final plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
ggplot(data = mpg) +
  geom_smooth(
    mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~drv, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]